# What vocabulary is more American?

Tags: word-meaning

Hello I have this two vocabulary at english :

```
when we are way upstairs
```

```
when we are up
```

that for example at spanish is similar, look this traslate to spanish:

```
when is :cuando
```

and

```
 we are : nosotros estamos
```

```
 way upstairs is: camino a arriba(I am walking up)
```

and

```
 up is : arriba at spanish
```

someone that speak english how language mother , can tell me what is more similar in a day daily in american (US)

I am very confused because for me this two vocabulary mean some similar , what is the more similar or common and American North?

I hope my question

Comment: I am not fluent in Spanish, but I don't think "way upstairs" corresponds to "camino a arriba". In "when we are way upstairs", way is being used as an adverb signifying "a great distance". See the adverb definition at  http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/way

Comment: Without other context, I would interpret "When we are up" as "When we are awake".

Comment: @MarkS. oh may be my question is bad?

Comment: It's not bad, but we could use more information. If there is context where you think two different phrases would fit, please provide it. If you heard these phrases and want to confirm their meanings, please provide the context where you heard them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither.

You would just say:

> When we are upstairs...

You seem to be translating a Spanish phrase *camino arriba* word-by-word. And in this case it doesn't work.

Saying "when we are up" would normally be taken to mean "when we are out of bed". One meaning of "up" is "out of bed" ([sense 3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/up?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)).

As noted in a comment "way upstairs" could mean "a great distance upstairs" ([way-2 (adverb) sense 2](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/way))

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to compare short sentence fragments like these.  Both could be used in different contexts

> We will talk about it when we are upstairs.
>
> When we are up there, we'll talk about it.
>
> We are on our way upstairs.

More information is needed to give you better examples.

Comment: +1. Yes, OP's question isn't clear, but I think you may have nailed it with "on our way".